# Speeding up SMTP sending

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp

I have here a working code using SMTP, i have used gmail as my server but i want to speed up the sending. I have tried setting the Timeout to 500 but it is still slow.

Here is my complete code:

```
Function SendEmail(ByVal Recipients As List(Of String), _
                  ByVal FromAddress As String, _
                  ByVal Subject As String, _
                  ByVal Body As String, _
                  ByVal UserName As String, _
                  ByVal Password As String, _
                  Optional ByVal Server As String = "smtp.gmail.com", _
                  Optional ByVal Port As Integer = 587, _
                  Optional ByVal Attachments As List(Of String) = Nothing) As String


    Dim Email As New MailMessage()
    Try
        Dim SMTPServer As New SmtpClient
        For Each Attachment As String In Attachments
            Email.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(Attachment))
        Next
        Email.From = New MailAddress(FromAddress)
        For Each Recipient As String In Recipients
            Email.To.Add(Recipient)
        Next
        Email.Subject = Subject
        Email.Body = Body
        SMTPServer.Host = Server
        SMTPServer.Port = Port
        SMTPServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, Password)
        SMTPServer.EnableSsl = True
        SMTPServer.Send(Email)
        SMTPServer.Timeout = 500
        Email.Dispose()

        Return "Email to " & Recipients(0) & " from " & FromAddress & " was sent."
    Catch ex As SmtpException
        Email.Dispose()
        Return "Sending Email Failed. Smtp Error."
    Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
        Email.Dispose()
        Return "Sending Email Failed. Check Port Number."
    Catch Ex As InvalidOperationException
        Email.Dispose()
        Return "Sending Email Failed. Check Port Number."
    End Try
End Function


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Recipients As New List(Of String)
    Recipients.Add("put recipient email here")
    Dim FromEmailAddress As String = Recipients(0)
    Dim Subject As String = "subject goes here"
    Dim Body As String = "Email body goes here"
    Dim UserName As String = "put username here"
    Dim Password As String = "put password here"
    Dim Port As Integer = 587
    Dim Server As String = "smtp.gmail.com"
    Dim Attachments As New List(Of String)
    MsgBox(SendEmail(Recipients, FromEmailAddress, Subject, Body, UserName, Password, Server, Port, Attachments))

End Sub
```

Is there anyway for me to speed this up or is this out of my control? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your email sending class seems correct. It will last less or more time depending on your network connection or the size of the attachments you are adding to the `MailMessage` class.

By the way, you are assigning the :

```
SMTPServer.Timeout = 500
```

after you are sending the email:

```
SMTPServer.Send(Email)
```

So it is not being assigned to the class and is not taken in consideration.

`TimeOut` is useful when your client loses network  connection ( so it doesn't wait to send forever) or the Server Email is not operative (is this case is gmail, not probable to happen).

TimeOut has nothing to do with sending speed, it will only accelerate the `Throw Exception` when something involving connection or server is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I gues there is nothing i can do about the sending speed then. Time to move on to another experiment :D

Comment: Email classes are pretty straightforward this is correct :). Move to another experiment ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
  smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //host name
    smtp.Port = 587; //port number
    smtp.EnableSsl = true; //whether your smtp server requires SSL
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
    smtp.Timeout = 20000;
```

Go through [Send Mail (SMTP) using ASP.NET and C# (smtp.Send() method)](http://programmers.bhoomijunction.com/Article/send-mail-smtp-using-asp-net-and-c-sharp-dot-net-smtp-send-method-38) for details